# sass-lint in Visual Studio Code mixed tabs with spaces

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code, lint, sass-lint

I just installed **[sass-lint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=glen-84.sass-lint)** in my **[VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)** editor and I keep on getting this error for each and every property(line) I've set in my `*.scss` files:

### `[sass-lint] Mixed tabs and spaces`

[image]

Indentation type in VS Code is set to tabs(4), it is set to indent using Tabs.

> **How can I disable mixing of tabs and spaces for sass-lint?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To close this one off, I later on found out that it is a best practice to use a **[EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/)** file to pre-set all of your workflow settings.

This is a plugin-type settings file, which pre-configures desired settings to fit your workflow.

> In my case, I use **[EditorConfig for VScode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig)**. After you add it to your editor of choice, simply create a **.editorconfig** file in your base(root) directory and fill it with the desired settings.

e.g. , my base setup looks like this:

```
# Editor configuration, see http://editorconfig.org
root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 4
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.md]
max_line_length = off
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

Answer (score 2):

The real reason is: SASS Lint isn't recognizing your indentation settings and it's using it default indentation (2 spaces). It's looking for 2 spaces and found tabs instead.

You can confirm it by removing all indentation and reading the hint.

As pointed on [Pull#725](https://github.com/sasstools/sass-lint/pull/725), the correct syntax is:

```
indentation:
  - 1
  -
    size: 'tab'
```

Comment: I've got this set in my config file and it is still throwing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I found that sass-lint in Sublime Text 3 wasn't loading my config file.

I got it working after reading this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/skovhus/SublimeLinter-contrib-sass-lint/issues/25):

In SublimeLinter preferences (Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeLinter -> Settings):

```
"linters": {
    "sass": {
        "working_dir": "${/home/myusername}"
    }
},
```

Add the file .sasslintrc to your Home folder:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "indentation": [
      1,
      {
        "size": "tab"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```